# How to get currently activated view?

Tags: objective-c

Hi in my project i have 3 views in a single .XIB file. I am using a scrollview to show one view at a time.(When we swipe only one view shown in the screen). Is there any way to identify which view is currently showing on the screen?

Comment: Views can have [tags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag?changes=_4&language=objc)

Comment: could you please explain with small code?
Actually i am a beginner in objective C

Comment: Try adding colors to each view so that you know if it scrolls. :)

Comment: A crude method would be to track scroll behaviour in `scrollViewDidEndDraggin:willDecelerate` and figure out which page you're on using the `contentOffset` property of the scrollView. `scrollView:WillEndDragging:withVelocity:andTargetContentOffset:` might be specially useful here.

Comment: @vadian yes i assign tag to each view. So how can i get back currently showing view's tag? All my 3 views are in a single view. (That means i have a single view that contains 3 subviews and only one subview shown at a time using scrollview)

Comment: Can you at least indicate what OS your question is about?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    // tag is 0 , 1 , 2
    NSInteger tag = scrollView.contentOffset.y / singleViewHeight;

}
```

Dont't for get to set the delegate

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you. But what is the value of  `singleViewHeight` ?

Comment: it should be the height of any view from the 3  (suppose they have same height)

Comment: But it always return value as 0.

**NSInteger tag =scrollview_page.contentOffset.y / 690;**

This is because my Y value of each view is 0.

Comment: @ Sh_Khan Thank you very much sir.  It worked for me. I change the `scrollView.contentOffset.y`  to `scrollView.contentOffset.x`  . Now i get the tag value of each views.

Comment: for horizontal make it x for vertical y